# How to create distinct pair of the same column by Joining?

Tags: sql, join, select

I have 2 tables:

**Space** `id_space(PK)`, `id_type`

**Offer** `id_agency`, `id_space(FK)`

These are the significant columns.

I need to create distinct pairs of `id_space1`, `id_space2` which are sold by the same agency(`id_agency`) and the two space having the same type(`id_type`).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results so we can understand this better. It's not clear how we are determine "Same `id_agency`" and "Same `id_type`" when both tables don't contain those columns. How do we detrmine the `id_type` of an `id_space` in `Offer`, for instance?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? PostgreSQL? etc.

Comment: I'm using Oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a self-join.  A CTE can help simplify the logic:

```
with os as (
      select distinct o.id_space, o.id_agency, s.id_type
      from offer o join
           space s
           on o.id_space = s.id_space
     )
select os1.id_space, os2.id_space
from os os1 join
     os os2
     on os1.id_agency = os2.id_agency and
        os1.id_type = os2.id_type and
        os1.id_space < os2.id_space
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct
    o1.id_space as id_space1,
    o2.id_space as id_space2
from (select id_space, id_type, id_agency from Space s inner join Offer o on s.id_type = o.id_type) o1 inner join (select id_space, id_type, id_agency from Space s inner join Offer o on s.id_type = o.id_type) o2
where o1.id_space  <> o2.id_space 
  and o1.id_type = o2.id_type
  and o1.id_agency = o2.id_agency
```

Comment: The problem is that i do not have a direct link to the id_type from the Offer table, I only have it in the Space table, and i think i should make another join here, but i don't know how to make it to be able to reference the id_type